# Efficient ay to process arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, computer-science, performance

Let's say I have the following arrays.

Array 1: List of cities (might have some entries that are same as array 2)
Array 2: List of cities

I want to output the following listS:

1. List of cities only in Array 1
2. List of cities only in Array 2
3. List of cities in both arrays

What is the most efficient way to accomplish 1-3?

I was thinking of storing the names of the cities in each array and then doing a foreach to compare the two.

Comment: Tests for existence are best done with hashed objects / dictionaries.

Comment: **Set intersection** is the term for what you are trying to do. What you propose will do the job, but it's not the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays were sorted you can traverse them in parallel:

```
index_1 = 0 // assuming zero based indexing
index_2 = 0

repeat the follwoing loop:
if( index_0 is out of range )
  count (remaining) cities from array 2
else if( index_1 is out of range )
  count (remaining) cities from array 2
else {
a = get city from array 1 with the index_1
b = get city from array 2 with the index_2
if( a = b ) {
  increment no. of cities in both arrays
  increment both indices
}
else if( a < b )
  count cities from array 1 until city from array 2 is b, update indices
else 
  count cities from array 2 until city from array 1 is a, update indices
}
end loop
```

This should do the job in linear time of array size.

If the arrays are not sorted sort them with an efficient sort algorithm.

If the arrays are small don't bother, use the brute force approach with nested loops.